# Running cloud function locally from emulator

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am sucessfully running local cloud function from postman with this url:

http://127.0.0.1:5001/spotnik-7de37/us-central1/getUsers

But on my app using:

```
val functions = Firebase.functions
functions.useEmulator("10.0.2.2", 5001)
functions.getHttpsCallable("http://127.0.0.1:5001/spotnik-7de37/us-central1/getUsers")
```

I get:
Failed com.google.firebase.functions.FirebaseFunctionsException: INTERNAL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Call functions from your app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#java). Just use the name of the function for the `getHttpsCallable()` call:

```
private Task<String> addMessage(String text) {
  // Create the arguments to the callable function.
  Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
  data.put("text", text);
  data.put("push", true);

  return mFunctions
    .getHttpsCallable("addMessage")
    .call(data)
    .continueWith(new Continuation<HttpsCallableResult, String>() {
        @Override
        public String then(@NonNull Task<HttpsCallableResult> task) throws Exception {
            // This continuation runs on either success or failure, but if the task
            // has failed then getResult() will throw an Exception which will be
            // propagated down.
            String result = (String) task.getResult().getData();
            return result;
        }
    });
}
```

In your case I might try the above example using:

`httpsCallable('spotnik-7de37')`

Or use this:

`getHttpsCallableFromUrl("http://127.0.0.1:5001/spotnik-7de37/us-central1/getUsers")`

Also ensure you are using the proper IP for your emulator:

`functions.useEmulator("127.0.0.1", 5001);`

Additionally, if you want to use the entire URL string for the call, you can use [getHttpsCallableFromUrl](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/functions/FirebaseFunctions#getHttpsCallableFromUrl(java.net.URL)).

Comment: val functions = Firebase.functions
functions.useEmulator("127.0.0.1", 5001)
functions.getHttpsCallable("http://127.0.0.1:5001/spotnik-7de37/us-central1/getUsers")

Still the same error

Comment: Try just `spotnik-7de37` or use `getHttpsCallableFromUrl`. Revised the answer to include that.

Answer (score 0):

Need to use HTTPS protocol and not HTTP. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_functions

> Instrument your app for HTTPS functions emulation Each HTTPS function
> in your code will be served from the local emulator using the
> following URL format:
>
> http://$HOST:$PORT/$PROJECT/$REGION/$NAME
>
> For example a simple helloWorld function with the default host port
> and region would be served at:
>
> **https**://localhost:5001/$PROJECT/us-central1/helloWorld

Comment: The problem is remains, still getting an error. From postman I am succeeded with http

Comment: See the other answer, in ` functions.useEmulator("10.0.2.2", 5001) ` change port to 127.0.0.1 try that?